# How to remove :hover state without using extra class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I am using `<button>` tag and giving red background on `hovering` of that `button`. But how can I remove that `:hover` state without using **extra class**.

Comment: Use `removeClass('datclass')` .....

Comment: By moving your mouse away from it? I don't understand...

Comment: Can we see the css/html code ?

Comment: `without using extra class`, why not?

Comment: @JonasGrumann after some time i need to remove that state. without refreshing and without doing any action

Comment: Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

```
.hover(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "active" )
}
```

This is from jQuery's docs - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

If you want to have a delayed job of sorts... you can use mouseenter (and leave, if you want custom stuff)

```
.mouseenter(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "active" )
}).delay(5000).removeClass( "active")
```

That should work... you might have to use a custom timeout? delay doesn't always do what I think it's going to, but I think that'll do.

Comment: I dont want any callback function. But I need to remove auto hover after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css for that specific element from Javascript. Otherwise, I would just use a n extra class...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the background color to *initial*  "after sometime" using script. Since the injected inline css has more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than your `:hover` pseudo selector, it'll no longer work.

Neither you're adding an extra class nor using any callbacks.

(*The timeout below is only used for demo purpose*)

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("after sometime!");
  $("div").css("background-color", "initial");
}, 4000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```